# How to return 2 COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have this table :

### forum_categories

- id
- title

### forum_topics

- id
- category_id (n-1 with forum_categories.id)

### forum_messages

- id
- topic_id (n-1 with forum_topics.id)
- first

I'd like to return `forum_categories.title` , `count(forum_topics.id)` *(I mean number of topic for that category)* , `count(forum_messages.id)` *(I mean number of messages for this topic where the field **first** is 0)*.

This is an example :

```
forum_categories            forum_topics            forum_messages
1   title1                  1   1                   1       1       0
2   title2                  2   2                   2       2       1
3   title3                  3   1                   3       3       1
                            4   1                   4       6       1
                            5   3                   5       7       0
                            6   3                   6       2       0
                            7   2                   7       1       1
                                                    8       3       0
                                                    9       5       0
                                                    10      7       1
                                                    11      5       1
                                                    12      1       0
```

The ouput must be :

```
title1      3       3 (topic 1=2 + topic 3=1 topic4=0
title2      2       2 (topic2=1 + topic7=1)
title3      2       1  (topic5=1 + topic6=0)
```

Tried somethings like :

```
SELECT forum_categories.description, 
       COUNT(forum_topics.id), 
       COUNT(forum_messages.id)
  FROM forum_categories 
  JOIN forum_topics 
  JOIN forum_messages ON forum_categories.id = forum_topics.category_id 
                     AND forum_topics.id = forum_messages.topic_id
GROUP BY forum_categories.id, forum_messages.id
ORDER BY forum_categories.date
```

But its absolutely far away from my target (and also I don't know how to check the *forum_messages.first* field! Any helps?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Jim Rubenstein this is a partial solution :

```
SELECT fc.description, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.id) topics, COUNT(fm.id) 
FROM forum_categories fc 
JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id 
JOIN forum_messages fm ON fm.topic_id = ft.id
GROUP BY fc.id ORDER BY fc.date
```

The problem of this query is that count **every** message from forum_messages, but I need to count these message for each topic only when **field=0** .

**EDIT 2**

I think I've found the solution :

```
SELECT fc.title, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.id) topics, COUNT(fm.id) 
FROM forum_categories fc 
JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, topic_id, first FROM forum_messages WHERE first=0) fm ON fm.topic_id = ft.id
GROUP BY fc.id ORDER BY fc.date
```

What do you think about? Can I better it?

Comment: MySQL doesn't throw an error when you don't specify criteria on a JOIN (IE: `JOIN forum_topics JOIN ...`), because it assumes this to be a `CROSS JOIN` -- a cartesian product -- which explains why your counts would be wrong.

Comment: yeah..i forgot the ON after the first Join :) thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* be able to accomplish this with the `DISTINCT` keyword.  You also want to `GROUP BY` the `category_id` so you get a count for topics/messages for each category.

```
SELECT fc.description, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.id) topics, COUNT(fm.id) messages
FROM forum_categories fc
JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id
JOIN form_messages fm ON fm.topic_id = ft.id
WHERE fm.first = 0
GROUP BY fc.id
ORDER BY fc.date
```

another option:

```
SELECT fc.description, COUNT(DISTINCT ft.id) topics, SUM(CASE WHEn fm.first = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) messages
FROM forum_categories fc
JOIN forum_topics ft ON ft.category_id = fc.id
JOIN form_messages fm ON fm.topic_id = ft.id
WHERE fm.first = 0
GROUP BY fc.id
ORDER BY fc.date
```

*note:* I aliased your tables to shorter names...because i'm too lazy to type the full names over and over. haha.

Comment: Yeah...in fact this should work :) But how can I select the rows on the table forum_messages there first=0? :) This is the last step...

Comment: Tried to add WHERE fm.first=0 but it take only those line! In fact I need to count all topic (with first=1) and the message only first=0...argh how can I do this? :)

Comment: I Should find the solution I think : `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, topic_id, first FROM forum_messages WHERE first=0) fm ON fm.topic_id = ft.id`

Comment: A Sub-query is going to kill performance, you should try to keep it in 1 query only.  if you remove the distinct keyword, you're going to get incorrect results for topics with more than 1 message.  I've also updated my response to deal with the `fm.first = 0` issue.

Comment: Yeah seems to work!! ;) Anyway, nobody have speak about subqueries :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries like:

```
 select (select count(*) from ...., select count(*) from ....)
```